# Return all matching rules for a given set of parameters

Tags: database, graph, amazon-dynamodb, search-engine, rule-engine

I'm looking for an efficient way of storing rules and retrieving the subset of matching rules for a given query.
Rules can contains three operators ( and, or , and not).
Example : Rules can be: 
 - Rule1  |  ( C1 and  C2) | 
 - Rule2  |  ( C3 or C2) and (C4 or C5) |  
 - Rule3  |  ( C3 and C4) | 
 - Rule4 |  ( C1 and (not C8) | 
 - Rule5 |  ( C2 ) |

Now for a user belonging to category set {C1, C2 , C5} , the qualifying rules are : Rule1, Rule2, Rule4 and Rule5.

What would be the efficient way of storing these rules, in terms of data model and datastructure/database. Key concern is the latency. < 10 ms

### Approaches

I am thinking :

- Persist the rules in a graph database with Categories as Nodes and relationships as logical operators (and, or, not). Then I can start with any of the nodes in the query set { c1, c2, c5} and traverse and pull out qualifying rules as I traverse. Main concern is the latency, as I have not previously worked with graph databases and can these even be cached.
- Use dynamoDB with DAX to store it in inverse indexing way, like Category => rules, mapping. So, for each category in query set , fetch the qualifying rules and then go through each of them and eliminate based on the rule criteria each has. Problem with this approach is, same rule will have to be repeated under each of the category index and this doesn't seem efficient.

  - Is elastic Search with percolator an option ?

Note : The categories are not pre-fixed, they can be added as new and can be in 100's. Any suggestions are welcome on how do i go about this?